# django uploading files without model

Tags: python, django

I would like to upload files (text/images) without a model  ( just using views and templates). I would ideally like to read or write to location.

My current code is as below:

In my template /foo/help/UploadFileContent.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="container">


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <form method="post" id="fileupload" action="/helpsubmitfilecontent/" accept-charset="utf-8" class="fill-up">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">

                                        <ul class="padded separate-sections">
                                            <li>
                                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
                                            </li>

                                            <li>
                                                <textarea name="content" id="content"
                                                          placeholder="Help Contents" style="height: 250px;width: 700px"></textarea>
                                            </li>
                                           <li>
                                                <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" />

                                           </li>
                                        </ul>

                                        <div class="form-actions">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue">Submit</button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

<script>
    $('#fileupload').submit(function(evnt){
       if($('#name').val().length <=0){
           $('#name').attr('style','border-color:red');
           evnt.preventDefault();
       }
       if($('#content').val().length <=0){
           $('#content').attr('style','border-color:red');
           evnt.preventDefault();
       }
    });

</script>
</html>
```

In my help views:

```
def fileupload(request):

    return responsewrapper('pages/foo/help/UploadFileContent.html', locals(),request)

def submitfilecontent(request):
    myhash = dict()
    myhash['name'] = request.POST['name'] # works
    myhash['filedata'] = request.POST['content'] # works
    handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['myfile']) # error throws up here.
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/successupload")

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('/home/foo/name.txt', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

The following error throws up while operating on the file data.

```
Exception Value:    
"Key 'myfile' not found in <MultiValueDict: {}>"
```

Please advice. I would ideally not like to use any databases, as all i want is to import text/images to static location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your `<form>` tag.

**Edit**

The argument to `handle_uploaded_file`, which you've called `f`, is an instance of UploadedFile, which according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/file-uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile) has a `name` attribute, so you could presumably change the destination depending on the name. Or you could look at the contents themselves and determine it that way.

Comment: How do we save the file to /opt/tmp/foo in the handle_uploaded_file(f), would not like to play with settings.py

Comment: I currently assume the user input is a text file, however it could be images and I would like to store it to /user/img1.{png/bmp/jpeg/*}

Answer (score 5):

you don't have to use models when you are uploading files. you can use this

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="sentFile" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and in the views

```
def myview(request):
    f = request.FILES['sentFile'] # here you get the files needed
    print f.name
```

Comment: How do we save the file to /opt/tmp/foo in the handle_uploaded_file(f), would not like to play with settings.py